# My DNS A records are not fully propagating

Tags: domain-name-system

I have the NS from my domain provider pointing to my server, which is hosting the DNS records. From the DNS records I have A records pointing to my other server where the website is hosted.
on a DNS propagation website I put in the URL and check A record and approximately 4 out of the entire list show the actual new server IP but the others still show the old one.

I have gone through the DNS records on the 1st server, i have reset the DNS and then reset them up again but this problem is not going away.

Is there an issue with my first server somewhere?

Comment: You need to wait until the TTL on your previous records expires before the new ones will be obtained.

Answer (score 1):

I literally just had to wait. Took nearly 4 days for some reason. The reason which I have not been able to find.

Comment: The reason would be the TTL configured on your DNS server. This is visible remotely by running `nslookup` then specifying `type=SOA` then looking up your domain. How you change this in your DNS server depends on which DNS server you are using. Since most registrars provide low cost or free DNS hosting, and you seem to be struggling, I would recommend NOT running your own DNS server.